# What would be a faster way to make a list of all the words of a file?

Tags: erlang, file-read

I want all the words of a file into a list. The size of the file is 6.3 MB containing around 1 million words only.
This is what I implemented, it takes around 3.5 seconds to make the list.
Any faster approach?

```
readfile(FileName) -> {ok,Binary} = file:read_file(FileName),
                  lists:map(fun(X) -> string:to_lower(binary_to_list(X)) end,(re:split(binary_to_list(Binary),"[^a-zA-Z]"))).
```

Comment: I'm guessing its the list data structures making this slow. You can at least remove the `binary_to_list` call in the argument to `re:split/2` for some speed up since `re:split/2` also accepts binary as the first argument. To make this as fast as possible in Erlang, I'd suggest doing the splitting using pattern matching instead of regex and doing the lowercase transform in the same code. I'll try to post an improved version if no one else answers in the next 12 hours.

Comment: ThankYou for the help, The answer posted helps me bring down the speed to around 2.5 seconds....Would be really nice of you if you could help in bringing the speed down to around 1-1.5 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something using [`string:tokens/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#tokens-2) will be faster:

```
readfile(Filename) ->
  Words = string:tokens(binary_to_list(Bin), " \t\r\n"),
  lists:map(fun(Word) -> string:to_lower(Word) end, Words).
```

The second argument is the list of characters to split on. If you want to split on other types of control characters refer to the [Erlang data_types page for the complete list](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id76887).

In my simple tests this function was almost 5 times faster. Test both functions on your dataset to verify this approach is faster. Performance will vary based on data.

Comment: Thank You! Brings the speed down to around 2.5 seconds for the file.......Would be glad if you could help bring the speed down to 1-1.5 seconds

Comment: @MishalShah I'd suggest trying to simplify this further. If you don't need the words in lowercase you can remove the `string:to_lower/1` call, which should speed it up. If you do need to make all the words lowercase you could spread the work across several processes, but that would make the code much more complex. Erlang is really about fault tolerance and scalability, performance comes second.